# Is there a way I can use to select from massive millions records from database to speed up without indexes in SQL Server and VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-insert, sql-optimization

I am working on project with VB.NET and SQL Server and I am trying to select from millions of records while inserting very massive data per millisecond and I want to speed up selection queries without indexes.

I tried to create indexes, it makes a lot of lock as I have to many delete and insert queries in the same milliseconds for large amount of data that leads to a lot of fails in execution time and more.

Is there any framework or more can help with this?

Comment: Creating an index in SQL Server will **not** cause locks..... the locks are there anyway, by means of any statement that modifies data (`DELETE`, `INSERT`  or `UPDATE` - and even  `SELECT` causes locks ......)

Comment: 1. Use `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint, if your database is not financial type. 2. Do `table partition` date wise. 3. Use proper where clause as per requirements means there is no `cast` or `convert` to any column at left side.

Comment: Thanks  a lot and totally agree
But it makes inserting,deleting quires too slow, is there anyway that I can use out of database